# How to merge curve and line shape together in svg path

Tags: html, css, svg, path, css-shapes

I have created an SVG shape in HTML and its a straight line with a curve in it. the problem is I don't know how to merge them I added Z Close Path command but it doesn't merge the shape as I want I researched a lot but I couldn't find a solution. below is the screenshot of a Shape that I want to achieve.

[image]

and the below shape is what I did which is fine but I want to merge all the path.

[image]

SVG CODE

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path stroke="blue" stroke-width=".7" fill="transparent" d="M14 10 H12 V35 H25 V10 H23 M14 10 C 14 17, 23 17, 23 10 " />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep only the first M command. I reversed your last curve so that you don't need move back to the first point. Also I've added a z command at the end of the `d` attribute to close the path.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <path stroke="blue" stroke-width=".7" fill="transparent" 
              d="M14 10 
                 H12 
                 V35 
                 H25 
                 V10 
                 H23 
                 C 23 17, 14 17, 14 10 z" />

</svg>
```

Comment: enxaneta. thanx brother i did this without M but i didn't add the last two numbers which are 14 10 that's why it doesn't work with me. anyways thanx again

Answer (score 5):

In case you want a CSS solution you can try this:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at top,transparent 13%,#f2f2f2 14%);
  border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 3px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Temani Afif. w0w you just made amazed me. i spend 3 days learning SVG to achieve this shape and it was just right there with CSS. can you please provide me some link on how can i use this trick. it will be appreciated and thanx brother.

Comment: @KinanAlamdar basically you have 2 things 1) the radial-gradient that allow you to have the hole as I simply create a circular gradient that start with transparent and end with color (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) 2) then the drop-shadow filter is like box-shadow but it will draw a shadow around the non-transparent part, it works with any kind of shape (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow)